# Edit questions and review your old downvotes!

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, down-votes, up-votes

I've been going through and aggressively editing questions to remove clinical context and personal information in order to bring out the (often valid) root question the person is asking.

I think this is another way we need to approach the floods of "diagnose me" "advise me" questions.  If we only downvote, it doesn't help the dilution of good questions.  This way we pull out the good in their question and increase the % of good questions.  Also, sometimes the answers to downvoted questions are great and deserve a good question stem!!

**Please, those who have downvoted, look at questions that have been revised and see if it deserves an upvote instead!  If not, consider revising it.**

This will greatly help us improve our questions - AND get us closer to completing beta.

EDIT: I don't mean immediately!  I haven't done dozens. But a decent number, and others have as well.  I just mean when you get a chance, check out some of them.

Comment: With ~100 downvotes, that's a lot of work. I'll double-check as soon as I'm on my Computer

Comment: Edited above, thx for mentioning that!